# Cordova - slide a div inside and outside of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, cordova

I'm creating a cordova app, and I have a left side menu that I want to slide in and out upon user request (clicking on something). The problem is that if the page has some content, the first time the menu slides in I can see its content, but when I slide it out, the next time I want to slide it in, i can see the div but the content is not being shown.

```
<style>
 .left-menu {
    transition: all ease 1s;
    left: -100%;
    ...etc...
  }

 .left-menu.active {
    left: 0;
  }
</style>

<div class="view">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="left-menu">..content...</div>
  ...some content that scrolls the page...
</div>

<script>
 var opened = false;

 $(".menu").click(function() {
   if(opened) {
     $("left-menu").removeClass("active");
   else
     $("left-menu").addClass("active");
   opened = !opened;
 }
</script>
```

This code works on Chrome browser on my desktop machine, but wont work on MotoX with Chrome 30.0.0.0 embedded webview, adobe cordova.

Comment: It's working ok on the same phone browser if I use it as an web app, but as a cordova app, I have the issue.

Comment: Is `opened` never being set to true?

Comment: Thanks, That's just a snippet code to deliver the idea, edited.